# Probleme when using the PATCH method to update salesOrderLines on SAP BUSINESS ONE service layer

Tags: service, layer

Here is the Error message i am receiving:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.0.4:50001/b1s/v1/Orders(334738)' from origin 'http://192.168.0.4:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field b1s-replacecollectionsonpatch is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

```
$.ajax({
        url: GlobalLink + "Orders("+DocEntry+")",  
        
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true  },  
        headers:  { 'B1S-ReplaceCollectionsOnPatch' :true  } ,
     
         data: jdata,   
         type: "PATCH",    
          dataType : "json",
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure Service Layer to allow this header in CORS requests. It can be done through the web interface "ServiceLayerController": [image: SL web configuration]

Just add your header "b1s-replacecollectionsonpatch" here separated by a comma.